# Apply same script to different files and write to different files

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote this script:

```
T = open("table")
out_T = open("table-1.out", "w")

table = []

for line in T:
    table.append(line.split())

print T

exp5 = ['qseqid', 'qlen', 'sseqid', 'slen', 'ipdent', 'length', 'length/qlen',]
table.insert(0, exp5)

for elem in table:
    out_T.write('\t'.join(elem) + '\n')


out_T.close()
```

however I need to apply it to lots of files in the one folder and write each to a new file. does anyone have a script I can add in to do this?

Comment: List files the target directory -> for loop over files -> for each file write into.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think I have script for you. The script will generate a list of `.out` filenames of the current directory, and it will iterate through the files by applying the the operations you wrote in the question to all the files one by one.

```
import glob,os
os.chdir("C:\\onefolder")
filelist=glob.glob("*.out")
for file in filelist:
    T= open("table")
    out_T = open(file, "w")

    table = []

    for line in T:
        table.append(line.split())

    print T

    exp5 = ['qseqid', 'qlen', 'sseqid', 'slen', 'ipdent', 'length', 'length/qlen',]
    table.insert(0, exp5)

    for elem in table:
        out_T.write('\t'.join(elem) + '\n')

    out_T.close()
```